# Conditional yshift in \newtcolorbox

Tags: conditionals, tcolorbox

I'm currently writting a book in xelatex, and in the progress of creating a couple of highlight boxes, I've encountered a problem.

Some boxes have titles and some doesn't have, because of that, the icon of the box get misplaced.

I've tried using `\ifx`, but that didn't work.

Here is the MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX spellcheck = es_ES
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,table,usenames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} % Para poder dibujar
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes,arrows,automata,positioning,graphs,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,svg.path,shapes.symbols,shadows,backgrounds}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Iosevka}[Scale=0.9]
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Highlight Boxes
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newfontfamily\titleboxfont{Fira Sans} % Font
\newfontfamily\boxfont{Fira Sans Light} % Font

\tcbset{mybox/.style={
        enlarge top initially by=5mm,
        enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
        fonttitle=\titleboxfont\bfseries,
        drop fuzzy shadow,
        height=3cm,
        height plus=10cm,
        enhanced,
        %    center,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=8pt,
        bottom=8pt,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        fontupper=\small\boxfont,
        arc=4pt,
        outer arc=4pt,
        leftupper=1.5cm,
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        title={#1}
    }
}

\colorlet{boxinfocolor}{blue}
\newtcolorbox{pinfobox}[1]{
    mybox=#1,
    colback=boxinfocolor!5!white,
    colframe=boxinfocolor!75!black,
    overlay={
%        \ifx #1\empty
%        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-0.65\baselineskip]frame.north west)
%        \else
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-2.65\baselineskip]frame.north west)
%        \fi
        {{\color{boxinfocolor!75!black}\fontsize{10mm}{10mm}\selectfont\faInfoCircle}};
    }
}


\newenvironment{infobox}[1]{%
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \begin{pinfobox}{#1}
        }
        {
        \end{pinfobox}
    \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{infobox}{Lipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{infobox}

    \begin{infobox}{}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

In the following picture you can see what is happening.

[image: Highlight boxes]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Your test doesn't work because when `#1` is empty, it becomes:

```latex
\ifx \empty
  \node[anchor=north west] ...
```

For TeX, this is exactly the same as:

```latex
\ifx\empty\node[anchor=north west] ...
```

Thus, TeX compares `\empty` to `\node` and the result is always false. What you wanted to do was probably something like this:

```latex
\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\empty
  〈something〉
\else
  〈something else〉
\fi
```

This works, you can use it. With this piece of code, the `\tmp` macro is defined with an empty replacement text if, and only if `#1` is empty. Thus, comparing the meaning of `\tmp` with that of `\empty` makes sense. Here is another way to test whether `#1` is empty and execute code depending on the outcome:

```latex
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  〈something〉
\else
  〈something else〉
\fi
```

Apart from that, I:

- added braces around `#1` in `mybox={#1}` in case someone uses a `#1` value that contains commas;
- converted your title argument to an optional one defaulting to empty, and
- removed a lot of unused things from your code. Please post a **minimal** example next time.

Here is the complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}            % only for demo code

\tcbset{
  mybox/.style={
    enhanced,
    enlarge top initially by=5mm,
    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    height=3cm,
    height plus=10cm,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=8pt,
    bottom=8pt,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    fontupper=\small,
    arc=4pt,
    outer arc=4pt,
    leftupper=1.5cm,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    title={#1},
  }
}

\colorlet{boxinfocolor}{blue}

\newtcolorbox{pinfobox}[1][]{
  mybox={#1},
  colback=boxinfocolor!5!white,
  colframe=boxinfocolor!75!black,
  overlay={
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\myFactor{0.9}  % <--- space token which doesn't matter
    \else
      \def\myFactor{2.65} % <--- ditto
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north west] at
      ([xshift=10pt, yshift=-\myFactor\baselineskip]frame.north west)
      {%
        \color{boxinfocolor!75!black}\fontsize{10mm}{10mm}\selectfont
        \faInfoCircle
      };
  }
}

\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]
  {\begin{figure}[htp]\begin{pinfobox}[#1]}
  {\end{pinfobox}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{infobox}[Lipsum]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{infobox}

  \begin{infobox}[]
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{infobox}

  \begin{infobox}
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

The aforementioned space tokens don't matter because they occur between Ti*k*Z statements—but feel free to add end-of-line percent signs if this makes you feel more comfortable. :-)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @frougon. Sorry about my MWE (it wasn't M enough). I promise it will be better in my next question. :o)

Answer (score 3):

The argument should be optional, in my opinion. You can get away more easily with `xparse`: a missing optional argument makes `\IfNoValueTF` return the “true path”

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[x11names,table,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % Para poder dibujar
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,matrix,shapes,arrows,automata,positioning,
  graphs,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,
  svg.path,shapes.symbols,shadows,backgrounds
}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\setmonofont{Iosevka}[Scale=0.9]
\newfontfamily\titleboxfont{Fira Sans} % Font
\newfontfamily\boxfont{Fira Sans Light} % Font

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Highlight Boxes
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tcbset{
  pablobox/.style={
    enlarge top initially by=5mm,
    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    fonttitle=\titleboxfont\bfseries,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    height=3cm,
    height plus=10cm,
    enhanced,
    %center,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=8pt,
    bottom=8pt,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    fontupper=\small\boxfont,
    arc=4pt,
    outer arc=4pt,
    leftupper=1.5cm,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    title={#1}
  },
}

\colorlet{boxinfocolor}{blue}

\NewTColorBox{pinfobox}{o}{
  IfNoValueTF={#1}{pablobox={}}{pablobox={#1}},
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west] at 
      ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-\IfValueTF{#1}{2}{0}.65\baselineskip]frame.north west)
      {\textcolor{boxinfocolor!75!black}{\fontsize{10mm}{0pt}\selectfont\faInfoCircle}};
  },
  colback=boxinfocolor!5!white,
  colframe=boxinfocolor!75!black,
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{infobox}{}
 {\begin{figure}[htp]\begin{pinfobox}}
 {\end{pinfobox}\end{figure}}


\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}[Lipsum]
\lipsum[1]
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Your solution taught new concepts. I have never got into ```xparse``` before. Perhaps with this, I will give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `interior` node and forget the problem with conditionals.

Look at `geometry nodes` in `tcolorbox` documentation. It explains that a `tcolorbox` defines four `nodes`: `frame` (title+box contents), `interior` (box contents), `title` and `segmentation`. Using `interior` as placement reference is a valid solution for boxes with o without title.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX spellcheck = es_ES
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names,table,usenames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} % Para poder dibujar
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes,arrows,automata,positioning,graphs,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,svg.path,shapes.symbols,shadows,backgrounds}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmonofont{Iosevka}[Scale=0.9]
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Highlight Boxes
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\newfontfamily\titleboxfont{Fira Sans} % Font
%\newfontfamily\boxfont{Fira Sans Light} % Font

\tcbset{mybox/.style={
        enlarge top initially by=5mm,
        enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
%        fonttitle=\titleboxfont\bfseries,
        drop fuzzy shadow,
        height=3cm,
        height plus=10cm,
        enhanced,
        %    center,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=8pt,
        bottom=8pt,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
 %       fontupper=\small\boxfont,
        arc=4pt,
        outer arc=4pt,
        leftupper=1.5cm,
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        title={#1}
    }
}

\colorlet{boxinfocolor}{blue}
\newtcolorbox{pinfobox}[1]{
    mybox=#1,
    colback=boxinfocolor!5!white,
    colframe=boxinfocolor!75!black,
    overlay={
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([shift={(10pt,-10pt)}]interior.north west)
        {{\color{boxinfocolor!75!black}\fontsize{10mm}{10mm}\selectfont\faInfoCircle}};
    }
}


\newenvironment{infobox}[1]{%
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \begin{pinfobox}{#1}
        }
        {
        \end{pinfobox}
    \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{infobox}{Lipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{infobox}

    \begin{infobox}{}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As @egreg, your solution gave me a different approach. Something new to learn. Thanks!